# Change overall font size of a chosen.js dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to change the font size of a chosen.js dropdown like this:

```
$(function() {
    $select.chosen({width: "100%", search_contains: true});
    $select.css('font-size', '10px')
});
```

But this leaves the font size unchanged, is there a way to do this through the chosen API, or alternatively through CSS? Note that I don't want to change the font-size of all my chosen dropdowns, I just want to change the font-size of this one.

Comment: have you tried `inherit_select_classes`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried this and it didn't work, the font-size stayed the same as before.

Comment: I was able to get something that sort of looks okay by disabling the `.chzn-container` font-size rule, the `.chzn-container-single .chzn-single` height and line-height rules and the `.chzn-container .chzn-results li` line-height rule, but that leaves the caret and the search icon incorrectly aligned.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure a way around this either.